# UICollectionview built in Xcode 6 but not show when running in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uicollectionview, xcode6

I have a problem when I run the app is built in `Xcode 6.0.1`, the `UICollectionView` just show the cell but there are not show images, content of label.

But when running in iOS 8, it can work fine. I don't know why. Can you help me to fix this issue?

Comment: I have this problem (labels not showing text) when running on an iOS 7 simulator. Does this problem also occur when running on a physical device with iOS 7?

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer in the Apple developer forums (it works for me):

Add to:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

The following line after you dequeue your cell:

```
cell.contentView.frame = [cell bounds];
```

Source: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1035019#1035019

Answer (score 0):

Your question not provides us enough information to reproduce your problem, check your data source, network, frames, constraints, reset your phone, simulator or new API for iOS8 and above.